# How to detect secret rooms' entrance?

Tags: greedy-cave

I was peacefully and joyfully wandering around in the cave, when suddenly I literally passed through the wall and found myself in a fancy room with carpets, ornements, a chimney and obviously someone living here and hiding his treasure for a long time...

In this so-called secret room you can found a golden chest, a crystal chest if I remember correctly (unlockable with a couple of crystals), a pot and the stairs for the next floor.

I wasn't really paying attention at the moment I get in the room. As they're pretty useful and rewarding, **how to detect their entrance ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it !

If you can spot **sparkles** on the wall, it means that you have found the entrance of a Secret Room !

[image: Sparkles on the wall]

Just as expected, some interesting parts of the story in those rooms. A golden chest, a crystal chest, a pot and the stairs. Also, you can often find notes on the desk, telling us more on the weird stuff that happens in the cave...

[image]